# Sharepoint images changes

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have a small client application in C# that sends images to a sharepoint site via a webservice. As the images can be quite large i need to check if the files has changed so that i dont need to send file again.

I check if the file has changed by calculation requesting a MD5 hash of the file from the server and comparing it with the hash of the file on the client.

What is strange is that this approach work with about 60% of my images , for the rest the server returns a different hash. If i download the file from sharepoint and replace the local one then the hash matches.

I have also tried with CRC32 with the same result

Does anyone know if Sharepoint adds information to image files when they are published to a standard asset library.

This is the function i use to calculate MD5

```
protected string GetMD5HashFromFile(byte[] file)
{
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(retVal[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I have compared the original file with the file published on sharepoint and the files are identical except for the file date.

**EDIT 2**

To clarify

On the client im calculating the hash by

```
byte[] buff;
using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    buff = ConvertStreamToByteBuffer(fs);
}

public byte[] ConvertStreamToByteBuffer(System.IO.Stream theStream)
{
    int b1;
    System.IO.MemoryStream tempStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    while ((b1 = theStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
    {
        tempStream.WriteByte(((byte)b1));
    }
    return tempStream.ToArray();
}
```

And then

```
string md5Local = GetMD5HashFromFile(buff);
```

On the server im just grabbing a listitem with CAML query and then calculating

```
string Md5 = GetMD5HashFromFile(oSPListItemCollection[0].File.OpenBinary());
```

Comment: are you using exactly the same code on the client and the server? how do you read the file(to byte[])?

Comment: Basically im grabbing a listitem and calculation MD5.  string Md5 = GetMD5HashFromFile(oSPListItemCollection[0].File.OpenBinary());

Comment: On answer to your first question , im using exactly the same code

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed, Sharepoint makes changes to image properties when you register them in SP